# A way to get a list of web services deployed on wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I am looking for a way with which I can get a list of all the web services deployed on wildfly, I looked around but I cannot find anything that fits the bill.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CLI you can execute the following command to show all the web services.

```
/deployment=*/subsystem=webservices:read-resource(include-runtime=true, recursive=true)
```

Example CLI output:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "address" => [
            ("deployment" => "helloworld-ws.war"),
            ("subsystem" => "webservices")
        ],
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {"endpoint" => {"helloworld-ws%3Aorg.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld.HelloWorldServiceImpl" => {
            "average-processing-time" => 0L,
            "class" => "org.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld.HelloWorldServiceImpl",
            "context" => "helloworld-ws",
            "fault-count" => 0L,
            "max-processing-time" => 0L,
            "min-processing-time" => 0L,
            "name" => "org.jboss.as.quickstarts.wshelloworld.HelloWorldServiceImpl",
            "request-count" => 0L,
            "response-count" => 0L,
            "total-processing-time" => 0L,
            "type" => "JAXWS_JSE",
            "wsdl-url" => "http://localhost:8080/helloworld-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl"
        }}}
    }]
}
```

You can also use the web console to see the endpoints. If you go to the Runtime tab, Standalone server, Subsystems and click "View" on Web Services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer James, I was able to find out about the deployment URL but the subsystem parameter you defined is going to be helpful.

Comment: Can you point me towards a tutorial that covers various operation you can perform using the CLI?

Comment: I'm not aware of a tutorial, but you can tab complete to see the operations. Or use `some=resource:read-operation-names`. For example `/deployment=*/subsystem=webservices:read-operation-names`.